# Como criar uma System Call para extrair dados de um processo em andamento?

Tags: c, linux, processo, kernel

Preciso fazer uma System Call que receba um PID como parâmetro e retorna o número de bytes que esse processo leu da entrada padrão, do disco, e quantos bytes ele escreveu na porta USB. Como sou meio novato na programação para Linux, estou meio perdido, mas pesquisando bastante descobri a System Call "ptrace" e acho que ela pode ajudar bastante. Estou usando o ambiente Ubuntu Kernel 4.3. Se alguém puder dar uma luz eu agradeço muito.

Comment: Acho que ptrace não permite monitorar um processo já ativo, pelo menos, todas as vezes que tive que usar foi necessário iniciar o processo com trace. Você chegou a olhar a documentação do diretório /proc ? Todas as estatísticas de um processo ficam no diretório /proc/[PID]; esse seria o meu ponto de partida.

Comment: Sua pergunta está com 4 votos para fechar como ampla demais neste momento (com 5 ela fecha). Entretanto, lendo a sua pergunta com atenção, ela me parece ser uma pergunta válida. O que você quer é usando o C no Ubuntu, descobrir quais são os dados de IO de um determinado processo para o qual você tem o PID. É isso? Se sim, sua pergunta é perfeitamente válida e não deveria ser fechada.